# Checkstyle with Gradle

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I'm trying to add checkstyle to my `build.gradle`.

Checkstyle template is of `commons-math3`, which can be accessed from [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/MATH_3_6_1/checkstyle.xml).

But this file uses `${checkstyle.header.file}` to check license declarations on the top of each source file.

```
<!-- Verify that EVERY source file has the appropriate license -->
<module name="Header">
  <property name="headerFile" value="${checkstyle.header.file}"/>
</module>
```

So I added below phrase in my `build.gradle`:

```
checkstyle {
    configFile = rootProject.file("commons-math-checkstyle.xml")
    headerFile = rootProject.file("license-header.txt")
    toolVersion = '7.8.1'
}
```

but it makes an error.

Removing `headerFile = rootProject.file("license-header.txt")` from `build.gradle` and making `Header` module in checkstyle xml file be wrapped by `<!--` and `-->` (i.e. disabling) makes checkstyle works well.

How can I declare `checkstyle.header.file` in my `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the property in your Gradle file:

```java
checkstyle {
    toolVersion '7.8.1';
    configFile file('commons-math-checkstyle.xml');
    configProperties 'checkstyle.header.file': file('license-header.txt');
}
```